# What is an alternative implementation for RWTPtrOrderedVector?

Tags: c++, rogue-wave

I'm trying to get rid of Rogue Wave dependencies. Is there a solid alternative implementation of RWTPtrOrderedVector? Would it just be std::vector?

Comment: If the answer provided answers your question, please accept it so that it appears solved. if not don't hesitate to gives additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Actually `RWTPtrOrderedVector`is implemented on-top of `std::vector`apparently :

> Class vector is the C++-standard collection that serves as the underlying implementation for this class.

http://docs.roguewave.com/legacy-hpp/tlsref/rwtptrorderedvector.html

I have no idea why they would create their own implementation though, so be careful, they might have added some functionality that you are using.